# Why can't I change the position & size values of a certain path to exact values?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I am trying to join two paths for a logo, but the paths are not aligning correctly, so I want to change the position and size to exact values so that they can match. This works well for all my paths in this project except for one:

If I want to edit the value it jumps right back to a close approximation of that desired value.
Same goes with changing the nodes itself: If I try to align one node from path A to match with node from path B, no problem occurs, but if I try to then get the second node beside the first node from path A to the equal height, the whole path jumps down.

I also made a video to see it in action: https://youtu.be/24Unf86jaLo

I guess it has something to do with the rasterization of that project, but can't get the hang on it.

Regards,
Nico

Comment: Snap to pixels is on for the one object?

Comment: Yep it was and that is what was causing the problem. Even though I don't understand why the path couldn't be placed at an exact pixel value, because I thought snap to pixels does exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe document is set do align objects to Pixel Grid.
this is set in the screen when you create a new document.

[image: new document window]

see Transform window. try unchecking the Align to Pixel Grid checkbox.
[image: Transform window]

Answer (score 0):

hope these can help.. check the exact location of that point.. then input the details on the other one you wish to place exactly on that position..

check also if you have lines (if with the same thickness).. 
i cant see clearly your video.. hope this help a bit..